# Where is WinUI3 in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, winui-3

I am unable to find Microsoft's new development platform WinUI3 in visual studio. Should I install any components or something bug in my VS?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to install the correct workload as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=vs-2022):

> Required workloads and components While installing Visual Studio 2022
> or 2019, select the following workloads and components.
>
> On the Workloads tab of the installation dialog, select:
>
> - Universal Windows Platform development .NET Desktop Development
>   Desktop development with C++ On the Individual components tab of the
>   installation dialog, make sure Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0) is
>   selected in the SDKs, libraries, and frameworks section.
> - In the Installation details pane of the installation dialog, make sure
>   C++ (v142) Universal Windows Platform tools is selected in the
>   Universal Windows Platform development section:

You also have to:

> 2. Install the Windows App SDK extension for Visual Studio (VSIX)
>    The Windows App SDK includes project and item templates for creating and developing WinUI 3 apps. These project templates are available as Visual Studio extensions (VSIX) for Visual Studio 2022 / 2019.

Comment: Works Perfectly.

Answer (score 14):

In the Visual Studio Installer under "Workloads / Installation details" at the right side, enable:

- ".NET desktop development" > "Windows App SDK C# Templates"
- "Desktop development with C++" > "Windows App SDK C++ Templates"

[image]

All other required features will be selected automatically.